# apache Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': free(): invalid next size (fast)

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu-14.04

My apache error log is filled with entries like below.

```
[Tue Dec 20 21:18:16.037877 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2067] AH00051: child pid 12421 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /tmp
*** Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00007f3dfdec01d0 ***
[Tue Dec 20 21:18:53.105789 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2067] AH00051: child pid 12716 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /tmp
*** Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x00007f3dfe9b0470 ***
```

I can't seem to locate the cause of the issue.  I've opened the core dump and couldn't really make any sense of it.  I'm looking for pointers on how to debug this issue.

core dump output:
% sudo gdb /usr/sbin/apache2 core

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /usr/sbin/apache2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/sbin/apache2...done.
done.
[New LWP 11290]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysql.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysql.so" (CRC mismatch).


warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysql.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysql.so" (CRC mismatch).


warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysqli.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysqli.so" (CRC mismatch).


warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysqli.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysqli.so" (CRC mismatch).


warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so" (CRC mismatch).


warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so" (CRC mismatch).

Core was generated by `/usr/sbin/apache2 -k restart'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x00007f3dfae2dc37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x00007f3dfae2dc37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
        resultvar = 0
        pid = 11290
        selftid = 11290
#1  0x00007f3dfae31028 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
        save_stage = 2
        act = {__sigaction_handler = {sa_handler = 0x7f3dfbd256e8,
            sa_sigaction = 0x7f3dfbd256e8}, sa_mask = {__val = {139904184910772,
              139899969732630, 139899969732608, 139899969732609, 140735729349512,
              139904184909536, 0, 140735729348896, 139899969732640, 0, 4224794192,
              140735729348792, 140735729348816, 140735729348788, 139904194526800,
              139904194540776}}, sa_flags = -70163096, sa_restorer = 0x7f3dfbd17178}
        sigs = {__val = {32, 0 <repeats 15 times>}}
#2  0x00007f3dfae6a2a4 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=1,
    fmt=fmt@entry=0x7f3dfaf786b0 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n")
    at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
        ap = {{gp_offset = 40, fp_offset = 32573, overflow_arg_area = 0x7fff9727b330,
            reg_save_area = 0x7fff9727b2c0}}
        fd = 2
        on_2 = <optimized out>
        list = <optimized out>
        nlist = <optimized out>
        cp = <optimized out>
        written = <optimized out>
#3  0x00007f3dfae74ff7 in malloc_printerr (action=<optimized out>,
    str=0x7f3dfaf74905 "realloc(): invalid next size", ptr=<optimized out>)
    at malloc.c:4996
        buf = "00007f3dfe4d6030"
        cp = <optimized out>
#4  0x00007f3dfae78827 in _int_realloc (av=<optimized out>, oldp=0x7f3dfe4d6020,
    oldsize=<optimized out>, nb=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:4234
        newp = <optimized out>
        newsize = <optimized out>
        newmem = <optimized out>
        next = <optimized out>
        remainder = <optimized out>
        remainder_size = <optimized out>
        bck = <optimized out>
        fwd = <optimized out>
        copysize = <optimized out>
        ncopies = <optimized out>
        s = <optimized out>
        d = <optimized out>
        errstr = <optimized out>
        __func__ = "_int_realloc"
        nextsize = <optimized out>
#5  0x00007f3dfae79ed9 in __GI___libc_realloc (oldmem=0x7f3dfe4d6030, bytes=5)
    at malloc.c:3029
        ar_ptr = 0x7f3dfb1b5760 <main_arena>
        nb = 32
        oldp = 0x7f3dfe4d6020
        oldsize = 32
        __func__ = "__libc_realloc"
#6  0x00007f3dfa3889be in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x00007f3dfbd25290 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x0000000000000033 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#9  0x00007f3d00000004 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#10 0x000000000000021f in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#11 0x0000000100000005 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#12 0x00007f3dfbcf3247 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#13 0x00007f3dfbd1fdb8 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#14 0x00007f3dfbd13e50 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#15 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
```

(gdb)

Loaded Apache Modules:

```
core_module (static)
so_module (static)
watchdog_module (static)
http_module (static)
log_config_module (static)
logio_module (static)
version_module (static)
unixd_module (static)
authz_cache_module (shared)
access_compat_module (shared)
alias_module (shared)
auth_basic_module (shared)
authn_core_module (shared)
authn_file_module (shared)
authz_core_module (shared)
authz_host_module (shared)
authz_user_module (shared)
autoindex_module (shared)
deflate_module (shared)
dir_module (shared)
env_module (shared)
expires_module (shared)
filter_module (shared)
headers_module (shared)
mime_module (shared)
mpm_prefork_module (shared)
negotiation_module (shared)
php5_module (shared)
remoteip_module (shared)
rewrite_module (shared)
setenvif_module (shared)
socache_shmcb_module (shared)
ssl_module (shared)
status_module (shared)
```

Comment: Run [valgrind](http://valgrind.org)